# How to enable a ng-wizard on mouse click

Tags: angular

[image]I'm Using ng-wizard, currently i can able to navigate to other wizards using only by next and prev buttons, how we can enable the other wizards so that to navigate using mouse clicks.

Other wizards were disabled until we reach to that wizard using next/prev buttons.

NgWizardService provides methods to show(),next(),previous(), used show(), but not as excepted, is there anything else we can do to enable that wizard.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapped `NgWizardConfig` to `ng-wizard` element. It worked as expected. Snippet below

```
enableAnchor: NgWizardConfig = {
    theme: THEME.default,
    toolbarSettings: { showNextButton: false, showPreviousButton: false },
    anchorSettings: { enableAllAnchors: true, markDoneStep: true },
};

<ng-wizard (stepChanged)="stepChanged($event)" [config]="enableAnchor">
```